# Remote Desktop and VPN Monitoring solution

Tags: remote-access

We have 20 users who do support for multiple customers. The issue is that when someone is logged into a customer via a VPN or Remote Desktop Session we have no way of telling unless we kick them out of the session. I am looking for a way to see the status of who is connected to what customer and what employee has made the connection.

So far the only thing that I can think of is to write an app for the router that would check the logs of the traffic going out.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on question and technologies used?

Comment: What I am looking for is something that can report a status. Customer Name, Customer IP, Support Tech Name.